# Lazy loaded route works with routerLink but doesn't with router.navigate

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a very simple main route defined as follow:

```
path: 'something',
loadChildren: () => import('./foo.module').then(m => m.FooModule)
```

the lazy loaded module has its own route defined:

```
path: '',
component: FooComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'edit',
    component: SecondComponent
  }
]
```

in the Foo.component.html I have a button defined as

```
<button  [routerLink]="'edit'">My Button</button>
```

And whenever I clicked the button it navigates correctly to the page of SecondComponent.

But if I change that to

```
<button (click)="tryToNavigate()">My Button</button>

public tryToNavigate(): void {
  this._router.navigate(['edit']);
}
```

it says that it cannot match any route 'edit'.

I've also tried using /edit both on the function and the route definition with no success.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Not really. I just updated to Angular 15/16, removed lazy loading and full embraced standalone. Way cleaner and fast.

Comment: I tried converting my pages to non lazy loaded and it still gives issues. Did you have any links with references?

Comment: Hi @RossRawlins I will link you a sort-of document I'll made in these days to solve this with lazy loaded modules. Key is to use the outlet name accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly set relative route:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

public tryToNavigate(): void {
  this._router.navigate(['edit'], {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you put a slash in front of edit, would it work?
Like this `this._router.navigate(['/edit']);`
If not, can you demonstrate the issue on Stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it worked when you use `routerLink` because it uses `relativeTo` implicitly, but when you use navigate method you need to provide it so that angular can navigate to the correct router.

So, when you only use `navigate` without `relativeTo`, it tries to navigate to path `edit` which is not defined at root but in the child route.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

public tryToNavigate(): void {
  this._router.navigate(['edit'], {relativeTo: this.route}); // make it work similar to routerLink
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, which I circumvented by breaking the navigation in two steps, which here would be like:

> ```
> this._router.navigate(['something']).then(() => {
>       this._router.navigate(['edit'])
> });
> ```

The first navigation triggers the module loading, so the second navigation can proceed to target.